# How to fix SDK error when using AZ pipeline and Static Web App with .net 5 AZ Function back end

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions, blazor-webassembly, azure-static-web-app

I am trying to use AZ Devops to deploy a Blazor WASM app with an in-process AZ function back end as stated in the question.  I keep getting an error and am stuck.  Any thoughts on how to get this to work would be appreciated.

My Pipeline is a simple one:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
  - checkout: self
    submodules: true
    
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    displayName: 'Use .NET Core 3.1 sdk'
    inputs:
      packageType: sdk
      version: '3.1.x'
  - task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
    inputs:
      app_location: '/Client'
      output_location: '/wwwroot'
      api_location: '/API'
      azure_static_web_apps_api_token: $(deployment_token)
```

and I am getting the error that the 3.1.0 sdk is needed, but I thought I was installing it in the previous step.  the error is:

[Error message from AZ Pipelines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ej7Lj.png)

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research I do not believe that the managed functions that come with the static web app will let you use in-process .Net Core 5 functions.  I just changed it back to a 3.1 function and it works as intended.  It would be nice to be able to do that, but what can you expect for free I guess.